# Unable to use explore "Identify" tool with ArcGIS Server vector data in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-pro, identify

How do I use the explore tool in ArcGIS Pro to list details of a vector data point the way ArcMap did with the identify tool?

The vector data is on an ArcGIS Server. ArcGIS Pro doesn't seem to be recognizing it as a selectable "layer" even though it is part of my contents catalogue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to the Explore Tool drop down and select "Visible Layers." That enabled the Explore tool to select my ArcGIS Server point data and display the details in a popup. Without that selected, it defaults to the selectable layers in the project.